# mips, mips, mips, mips, mips, mips, mips

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Does anyone know the source of the plague of [mips assembly language questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mips?sort=newest)? What institution of higher [sic] learning thinks that it makes sense to teach people to implement more or less complex algorithms in assembly at all, let alone mips?

**edit**

snark aside, I posted this question because I was, in fact, authentically curious. Fun though it may be I see no need for further debate on the merits of the teaching style thus revealed.

Comment: Well, at least they're not teaching them blatantly incorrect info. We constantly see students on Server Fault who are asking questions about things that *don't exist any more* because they were taught them as "current" in class last week.

Comment: This belongs on Programmers...

Comment: Why is there a *[sic]* on 'higher'? O.o

Comment: Your second question, is assembly still relevant or useful for programmers to learn, belongs on stack overflow.

Comment: @Dav because it seems to me a bizarre theory, that reflects poorly on whatever institution, to expect kids to learn to code, and *debug*, complex algorithms in assembly before, apparently, they are capable of doing them in a friendlier environment.

Comment: @Adam: I think the question of whether assembly is relevant or useful might belong on Programmers, but not on SO.

Comment: @Gabe probably so.

Comment: @Gabe - I'd question that assumption.

Comment: The University of Pittsburgh uses MIPS within their Computer Organization & Assembly Language class (it is core). We implement two complex programs per term. I feel that learning assembly is quite helpful.

Answer (score 7):

About all of them afaik, it's what the CS students learn.  MIPS started at Stanford.  John Hennessy was the Computer System Laboratory director there, later President of Stanford and founder of MIPS Computer Systems.  Well covered by text books and tools (assembler + emulator) available to academia.  Learn to learn, it doesn't have to be practical.

Comment: It's not what CS students learned when I was one at MIT in 1980. We learned algorithms and structure using scheme or lisp, and looked at machine architectures by writing compilers for them.

Comment: Yup, academia has been impractical for well over 30 years.

Comment: @Rosinante: If these classes were taught in Scheme, we'd be getting the exact same question, only it would be "How do I do X in Scheme" instead of "How do I do X in MIPS"?

Answer (score 7):

The reason to teach assembly is so that people understand how computers actually work. Otherwise we get ridiculous questions like "How come bytes from my binary file print in decimal?" and "Is `goto` faster than `while`?". Also, understanding addresses and adressing helps people understand pointers. And heaven forbid you should try to teach compiler construction to a class of students who don't know assembly!

The reason to teach MIPS, as opposed to some other architecture, is that it is relatively simple. Architectures like x86, Itanium, POWER, and M68k are all more complicated. (You can disagree, but the more common architectures are more complicated in my opinion.) And then when you go to design your own CPU (in VHDL, perhaps), an R2000 is pretty easy to design.

The reason to teach complex algorithms (if you think recursion and sorting are complex) in assembly is so that students learn how to actually *use* the language, rather than just learn its instructions. What would you suggest they teach in assembly?

Keep in mind that it's unlikely that many places teach assembly as a *first* language (I've always thought BASIC or Python would be best for that). It's also likely that most students in these classes really do understand how to do their assignments, and it's only a few who are way behind that post their problems to SO.

Comment: *And heaven forbid you should try to teach compiler construction to a class of students who don't know assembly!* - Sadly, my university now does this (fortunately after I went through undergrad). I can attest to it being a horrible idea.

Comment: I really like m68k. Sure ignore the BCD bits and a few other things, but it is so *nice*. 'Course, I'd learned 6502 and MIX first, and there is something to be said for really *simple* instruction sets.

Comment: @dmckee: M68k is great to program in, but hard to learn with all those address modes, different types of registers, and such. Of course coding for a 6502 is like programming a Turing machine. :)

Answer (score 1):

[McGill ECSE 221 - Introduction to Computer Engineering](http://csus.cs.mcgill.ca/wiki/ECSE-221) *could* be one of the sources. An assignment could be due this week as finals are soon. The second half of the semester has a lot of MIPS.

Module 1 - Data Representation
Module 2 - Combinational Logic
Module 3 - Sequential Logic
Module 4 - Assembly Language. <-- mips, mips, mips, mips, mips, mips, mips
Module 5 - Computer Arithmetic
Module 6 - Computer Architecture

The last set of assignments and final always has two or more questions on it.